# Can't resolve 'rxjs/Observable'

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've just been attempting to upgrade an old Angular 7 project to Angular 8 and I'm hitting a strange Rxjs dependency issue. Npm install runs fine but on trying to start the application I'm getting the following -

```
ERROR in ../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/Observable' in 'C:\Users\chris\source\repos\myapp\node_modules\@angular\core\@angular'
ERROR in ../node_modules/@angular/http/@angular/http.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/Observable' in 'C:\Users\chris\source\repos\myapp\node_modules\@angular\http\@angular'
ERROR in ../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/Subject' in 'C:\Users\chris\source\repos\myapp\node_modules\@angular\core\@angular'
ERROR in ../node_modules/@angular/forms/@angular/forms.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/observable/forkJoin' in 'C:\Users\chris\source\repos\myapp\node_modules\@angular\forms\@angular'
ERROR in ../node_modules/@angular/forms/@angular/forms.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/observable/fromPromise' in 'C:\Users\chris\source\repos\myapp\node_modules\@angular\forms\@angular'
ERROR in ../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/observable/merge' in 'C:\Users\chris\source\repos\myapp\node_modules\@angular\core\@angular'
ERROR in ../node_modules/@angular/forms/@angular/forms.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/operator/map' in 'C:\Users\chris\source\repos\myapp\node_modules\@angular\forms\@angular'
ERROR in ../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/operator/share' in 'C:\Users\chris\source\repos\myapp\node_modules\@angular\core\@angular'
```

My package.json looks like this -

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^13.0.3",
    "@angular/animations": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    ...
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.3",
    ...
}
```

Has anyone come across this before?

Comment: What typescript version are you on? Also have you tried running this `npm install --save rxjs-compat` to find the compatible version?

Comment: You can try to remove your `node_modules` folder completely by running `rm -rf node_modules` before you `npm i`. I ran into corrupt states sometimes. At least it's worth a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's a problem of dependency alignment between Angular 8 and RxJS, so, to solve it you need to downgrade your rxjs version from 6.5.3 to 6.4.0.

```
npm i rxjs@6.4.0
```

This is package.json file

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^8.2.2",
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
}
```

[Stackblitz link project angular8-rxjs](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-2esiut?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

[GitHub link project](https://github.com/chetouimohamedaziz/angular8-rxjs-project)

I hope we have a useful response and clearly written.